# How to remove '^@' characters in file in datastage?

Tags: file, character, datastage

I was facing same issue `'^@'` was appearing at end of each line of my fixed width file. As per senior's suggestion I tried using this command `tr -d '\000'` in the filter option of sequential file stage , however job run time which earlier ran in less than a *60 sec* has been running now for like *15 mins*. So i had to forcefully abort it. I want to remove this junk character from my file. Can you please suggest how to achieve this ?

Comment: Hi All, can anyone please provide their input ?

Comment: Can you share the sample input and output you want??

Comment: I think you could resolve your problem with a shell script, invoked from a sequence

Answer (score 0):

You can create a VBScript to delete the characters which you do not need and use an execute command stage in Datastage to call the script at each run.